# Unknown Column In Field List - Field Does Not Exist on Entity

Tags: mysql, entity-framework-6, .net-6.0

I'm having an issue figuring out where Entity Framework is getting the list of column names to query from a MySQL database. Essentially, when I am querying my context for a list of Discounts, a seemingly random property is getting attached, which doesn't exist in the database. I can't seem to find where, so I'm hoping someone has some troubleshooting guidance for me.

I have a Discount entity, that inherits off of my 'EntityBase' class.

```
public class Discount : EntityBase
{
    public Discount(){}
}

public class EntityBase
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

When I attempt to query discounts...

```
var discount = _myContext.Discounts.FirstOrDefault();
```

I get the following error - `Unknown column 'd.AttendeeBadgeId' in 'field list'`

Now, I DO have an `AttendeeBadge` entity, and I have a variety of other entities that utilize the `AttendeeBadge`. But I have absolutely nothing in the `Discount` class that utilizes the `AttendeeBadge` entity. I just have the Id property that gets inherited through `EntityBase` - and yet, my generated MySQL query is...

```
SELECT `d`.`Id`, `d`.`AttendeeBadgeId`
FROM `Discount` AS `d`
LIMIT 1
```

I've validated that in my modelBuilder for my context, I'm not mapping any particular properties that would cause an issue.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Discount>().ToTable("Discount");
modelBuilder.Entity<Discount>().HasKey(_ => _.Id);
```

I thought something might be cached, but I've deleted all of the bin/obj folders for every single project in my solution, and I used Notepad++ to validate all of the areas that I reference the string value "AttendeeBadgeId", and I just get the other classes that reference it.

I'm at a loss here, would anyone know how I could see how the context is generating the SQL query in a more verbose way, or see where that column is coming from?

Answer (score 0):

I should have tried harder before posting.

It turns out I had a property on the `AttendeeBadge` entity that had a list of Discounts.

```
public class AttendeeBadge : EntityBase
{
    public AttendeeBadge ()
    {
        Discounts = new HashSet<Discount>();
    }
    public ICollection<Discount> Discounts { get; set; }
}
```

This was causing Entity Framework to assume there was a relationship between the `Discount` and the `AttendeeBadge` when I removed that dependency earlier today. I found out by copying the Discount class to another class, and then re-mapping my entities until I found the culprit causing my issue.